# Can we provide H2O Flow UI a user based access?

Tags: h2o

I need to provide user based access to H2O Flow UI as the similar group users can see each others Flow and other group user are not able to see it.

Comment: I'm no expert with h2o but as a bystander, I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking. Please consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: I need to use h2o flow UI in such a way that different people can login on it and users in a same group can share their flows among themselves and people with different groups cannot do the same.